# Insert a value from a dataframe into another dataframe picked by ID and year

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 as below -

```
ID1 <- c(155,487,102,666,100)
year <- c(2002,2003,2002,2000,2004)
df1 <- data.frame(ID1, year)
df1
  ID1 year
1 155 2002
2 487 2003
3 102 2002
4 666 2000
5 100 2004
```

Then I have a dataframe df2 as below -

```
library(dplyr)
ID2 <- c(487,334,555,100,250,366,155,788)
a <- c(0.3,0.33,1.34,0.96,1.9,2.23,0.43,3.73)
b <- c(0.55,0.63,0.46,.26,3.1,0.4,2.46,4.34)
c <- c(0.78,0.83,0.34,0.95,0.12,0.72,0.52,0.03)
d <- c(2.3,1.23,2.35,0.96,0.1,0.78,0.49,2.03)
e <- c(1.3,0.53,1.54,1.36,2.34,0.34,0.25,1.33)
df2 <- data.frame(ID2,a,b,c,d,e)
df2 <- rename(df2, "2000"=a, "2001"=b, "2002"=c, "2003"=d, "2004"=e)
df2
  ID2 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
1 487 0.30 0.55 0.78 2.30 1.30
2 334 0.33 0.63 0.83 1.23 0.53
3 555 1.34 0.46 0.34 2.35 1.54
4 100 0.96 0.26 0.95 0.96 1.36
5 250 1.90 3.10 0.12 0.10 2.34
6 366 2.23 0.40 0.72 0.78 0.34
7 155 0.43 2.46 0.52 0.49 0.25
8 788 3.73 4.34 0.03 2.03 1.33
```

I want to pick values from df2 and insert it into df1 if ID1 of df1 matches ID2 of df2.
The column of df2 the value is to be picked from is named in column year of df1.

The result should be this -

```
  ID1 year value
1 155 2002  0.52
2 487 2003  2.30
3 102 2002    NA
4 666 2000    NA
5 100 2004  1.36
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: @Quinten the data shared is is in a text format hence reproducible. Note that unless the data is complecated, `dput` is not necessary. The idea is to be able to visualize the data in a table format yet dput does not do that. run the code `readr::read_table(' ID1 year
1 155 2002
2 487 2003
3 102 2002
4 666 2000
5 100 2004')` to reproduce the same in R

Answer (score 3):

We may reshape the second data to 'long' format and then do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
  mutate(ID2 = as.character(ID2)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID2, names_to = 'year') %>% 
  left_join(df1 %>% 
             mutate(across(everything(), as.character)), .,
     by = c("ID1" = "ID2", "year"))
```

-output

```
 ID1 year value
1 155 2002  0.52
2 487 2003  2.30
3 102 2002    NA
4 666 2000    NA
5 100 2004  1.36
```

---

Or using `base R` with `row/column` indexing created with `match`

```
df1$value <- df2[-1][cbind(match(df1$ID1, df2$ID2), 
                      match(df1$year, names(df2)[-1]))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID1 = c(155L, 487L, 102L, 666L, 100L), year = c(2002L, 
2003L, 2002L, 2000L, 2004L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))

df2 <- structure(list(ID2 = c(487L, 334L, 555L, 100L, 250L, 366L, 155L, 
788L), `2000` = c(0.3, 0.33, 1.34, 0.96, 1.9, 2.23, 0.43, 3.73
), `2001` = c(0.55, 0.63, 0.46, 0.26, 3.1, 0.4, 2.46, 4.34), 
    `2002` = c(0.78, 0.83, 0.34, 0.95, 0.12, 0.72, 0.52, 0.03
    ), `2003` = c(2.3, 1.23, 2.35, 0.96, 0.1, 0.78, 0.49, 2.03
    ), `2004` = c(1.3, 0.53, 1.54, 1.36, 2.34, 0.34, 0.25, 1.33
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using lookup:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~ID1, ~year,
  155, 2002,
  487, 2003,
  102, 2002,
  666, 2000,
  100, 2004
) |> 
  mutate(index = str_c(ID1, year))

df2 <- tribble(
  ~ID2, ~"2000", ~"2001", ~"2002", ~"2003", ~"2004",
  487, 0.30, 0.55, 0.78, 2.30, 1.30,
  334, 0.33, 0.63, 0.83, 1.23, 0.53,
  555, 1.34, 0.46, 0.34, 2.35, 1.54,
  100, 0.96, 0.26, 0.95, 0.96, 1.36,
  250, 1.90, 3.10, 0.12, 0.10, 2.34,
  366, 2.23, 0.40, 0.72, 0.78, 0.34,
  155, 0.43, 2.46, 0.52, 0.49, 0.25,
  788, 3.73, 4.34, 0.03, 2.03, 1.33
) |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID2, names_to = "year") |> 
  mutate(index = str_c(ID2, year))

df1 |> mutate(value = df2$value[match(index, df2$index)])
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>     ID1  year index   value
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1   155  2002 1552002  0.52
#> 2   487  2003 4872003  2.3 
#> 3   102  2002 1022002 NA   
#> 4   666  2000 6662000 NA   
#> 5   100  2004 1002004  1.36
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>